# How to handle an empty http-response?

Tags: angular

I have a service contains following method:

```
getCurrentJobByPersonId(personId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/persons/'+personId+'/currentjob').map(res => res.json()); 
}
```

If a person has no job, I receive an empty response and get "ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
 at Object.parse ()...". Is it ok to handle an empty response like this

```
getCurrentJobByPersonId(personId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/persons/'+personId+'/currentjob').map(res =>{
        if (res && res.toString.length>0) {
            res.json();
        }
});
```

or there is a right way? or should I always receive a nonempty http-response?

at the backend:

```
@RestController
```

public class JobController {

```
@Autowired
private JobService jobService;

@RequestMapping("/persons/{id}/currentjob")
public Job getCurrentJob(@PathVariable String id) {
    return jobService.getCurrentJob(id);        
}
```

}

Comment: That depends on the service method, dear Kate. Could you show us it's code?

Comment: Could you add the json response that you receive if a person got a job?

Comment: @Kate Are you getting error client or server side? If client-side, Did you define an interface for Person that has something like jobId? If so, did you try making it optional like this export interface Person {
jobId?: string;}

Comment: PS: I'm assuming that's Java/Spring on the server. If so, the tags for the post might need a tweak.